# Bug when i input "0" before the number

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm having problem when i want to input `0` before the number, but everything works fine when i only input the number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int input, output;

    printf("Enter number : ");
    scanf("%i",&input);

    output = input % 7;
    printf("%i", output);

    return 0;
}
```

For example :

- when i give input `8`, the output is `1`. But when i input `08`, the output is `0`
- when i give input `100`, the output is `2`. But when i input `0100`, the output is `1`

I know simply don't type `0` before the number is faster, but i wonder if it's possible to type `0` before the number without bug.

**I use Code::Blocks 16.01 (MinGW) on Windows 10 x64.**

Comment: If you type a leading 0, you choose the octal representation of numbers, e.g. 0100 in octal is the same as 64 in decimal representation. 64 % 7 = 1. Thus, this is no bug.

Comment: @camelCase I see, but i wonder if i can type "0" before number without change it to octal (stay as decimal/base 10)

Comment: @sandyKhosasi Use `%d`.

Comment: `scanf` is evil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `%i` in combination with a prefixed `0` (`08`, `0100` etc..) makes `scanf` interpret the input as an octal number which is base 8, not base 10. If you want `scanf` to ignore this you should use `%d` instead.